# Returning a point by a specific pixel value or range using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, point, coordinates

I have an image classified with pixel values equals to one and zero. I want to return the lat and long from pixels values equals to one, would be possible, using GEE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.selfMask()` to remove all zero values, then `.sample()` your image after adding `.pixelLonLat()` to retrieve the pixel values.

To convert the pixel values to a list, you can use `.aggregate_array('longitude')` and `.aggregate_array('latitude')`, or use `.reduceColumns()` using whichever reducer you need to provide the results you're looking for (e.g. `mean()`, `minMax()`, `toList()`, etc.)

```
// These weren't shared in the original question so still to define:
// image - your image of interest
// roi - your region of interest

// Mask zero values, add PixelLonLag, clip to roi
var imgWithPixLonLat = image.selfMask().addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat()).clip(roi)

// Pixel longitude values as a list
print(imgWithPixLonLat.sample().aggregate_array('longitude'))

// Mean lon/lat values 
print(imgWithPixLonLat.sample().reduceColumns({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().repeat(2),
                                         selectors: ['longitude', 'latitude']
}))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. I just needed to add scale attributes to ".sample" to avoid this error:  "The default WGS84 projection is invalid for aggregations. Specify a scale or crs & crs_transform."